# Android : How to create advance (complex) Listview and to handle?

Tags: android, listview

I am working android app, where i need  a Listview which contain different types of view sets.
They have to update dynamically. i.e , initially i have some list of views, with one header.
Next when i click button i have to add new view set with different header. So can any one tell me . how to achive this complex listview.

ex.
My list looks like

initially looks like this

**Countries (Header)** 
  (Each row contain text and image)

- India
- Australia
- America

next when i click button , i have to update listView like ....
**Countries (Header)** 
  (Each row contain text and image)

- India
- Australia
- America

**Currencies(Header)**
(Each row contain textview button , progressBar)

- Rupee
- Australia dollar
- Dollar

Can any one help me to resolve this ?
With some example ?

Thanking you,
Srinivas

Answer (score 0):

You should set an Adapter to your ListView. Adapter will contain something like State member. In getView() State could be checked and the corresponding layout will be inflated to each item in the list. Does it fit your needs?

Example:

```
public enum States{
  Countries,
  Currencies
}

private States mState;

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
if( mState == States.Countries )
   {
      return layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.countrie_layout, parent, false);
   }else if( mState == States.Currencies )
   {
      return layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.currencie_layout, parent, false);
   }
}
```

Comment: I am not getting , what exactly state member is ?

Comment: I've added an example to my answer. look at it.